# Why is Google Analytics saying that I got 5 clicks for each query?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, web-development, analytics

I have two websites, which I have been tracking with GA for 3-4 months now. In either of the site's reports, I have lots of queries shown in `Traffic Sources -> Search Engine Optimization -> Queries` window. However, all of the numbers shown in **Clicks** column are either 5 or 0. Do you think this is a bug ? Below are the screencaps for queries window for both of my sites' GA pages :

[image]
The second site is more rich in content, and it has only one query which it shows 12 as the click number :
[image]

Or did I really get 5 clicks for each of those queries, over 3 months ?

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed the same. Google uses an approximate number. It only shows 0, 5, 12, 20 (not sure of the actual numbers) instead of the real number. If you check Webmaster Tools, you'll see the same. I only get 1200, 1600 or 2000 clicks, never anything in between.

Comment: Thanks for our answer Ivo! I was starting to freak out :) And wow, good numbers :)

Comment: Those are for total clicks per day, not for single queries. I wanted to say that most of Google's numbers are approximates and use that as an example but somehow forgot to mention that.